# 3rd party add-ons in new Android SDK manager

Tags: android

I downloaded the new 4.0 SDK and I had to update the SDK manager to do it. I would like to use the Google API's in one of my applications, but now I can't find where to install it, because the "Third party add-ons" option does not appear. Please help me, where can I find this in the new manager. Thank you!

Comment: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list.xml 404 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running SDK Manager from Eclipse? I had the same problem, but third party repositories showed up when I ran `android-sdk/tools/android` manually from command-line.

Comment: I accept this answer, because you tried to help me. The problem solved, an XML file were missing from Google's servers and that was why I did not see the Third party addons.

Comment: coelho: Could you please say the name of XML file? I have the same problem. thanks